# Adding css to my container on button click

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to add a padding-top to my container on button click, but its not adding the paddint-top to my container.

```
$('#login').on('click', function(){
   $('#loginform1').css('padding-top', 120);        
});
```

Is there something wrong i am doing here?

Comment: Are you waiting the DOM to be ready?

Comment: try wrapping your code with `$(function(){/*your code*/});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed to specify the padding in pixels. Try,

```
 $('#loginform1').css('padding-top', '120px');
```

Full code would be,

```
$('#login').on('click', function(){
  $('#loginform1').css('padding-top', '120px');        
});
```

---

As the commentator said, there is no problem in not specifying the pixels but still i would suggest you to use that for avoiding confusions with plain css, If i speculate, then the problem might be with your ready handler, Try to wrap your code inside the document's ready event,

```
$(function(){
    $('#login').on('click', function(){
      $('#loginform1').css('padding-top', '120px');        
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wMv9e/2/)

try this

```
 $('#login').on('click', function(){
       $('#loginform1').css('padding-top', '120px');        
    });
```

Wierd either way it works with or without mentioning px